# How do I search for suitable NuGet packages?

Tags: visual-studio, search, nuget-package

The search function in Visual Studio for NuGet packages is not really good, is it?

I was just searching for a package which defines units of measurement. ChatGPT suggested UnitsNet, that's how I know about that. But when I enter "units of measurement" into the NuGet package search bar in Visual Studio, it does not show up! It only shows libraries with much less downloads, actually only one result has over 10k downloads.
The package has the text "units of measurement" in the description, it has the tags "units" and "measurement", yet the search function does not show it.

Comment: Have you tried via the browser at https://nuget.org? It appears to provide a slightly more flexible approach to searching. Once you know the package name, you can use the Visual Studio feature to go straight to that package.

Comment: @DavidOsborne I just tried it, it gives the same results as in Visual Studio

Comment: Yes, it does look the same. I notice that UnitsNet uses the tags `units` and `measurement` but not `units of measurement`, so searching for `units measurement` finds it in VS.

Comment: @DavidOsborne Yes. But such a limited search function isn't really good for finding a library for a certain purpose. It should at least search the description, and also not be thrown off by the common word "of".
Well, I have tried other ways to search for this kind of library, but each way is missing at least one result with many downloads. I was hoping there is a really good way to search